# Python list only folders that contain specific subfolders

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a script that will list all folders and subfolders and create a JSON file.  What I am trying to have is only folders that contain subfolders named "Maps" or "Reports" listed.  If they contain those then only the parent folder will be listed, so  "Maps", "Reports" would not be shown.  Currently stuck on how to accomplish this, any help would be great.

```
import os, json, sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
path = "G:\Testfolders"

def get_list_of_dirs(path):

    try:
        output_dictonary = {}
        list_of_dirs = [os.path.join(path, item) for item in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, item )) and os.path.isdir("./Maps") and os.path.isdir("./Reports")]

        output_dictonary["text"] = path.decode('latin1')
        output_dictonary["type"] = "directory"
        output_dictonary["children"] = []
        for dir in list_of_dirs:
        output_dictonary["children"].append(get_list_of_dirs(dir))
        return output_dictonary
    except WindowsError:
        pass

    print json.dumps(get_list_of_dirs(path))

with open(r'U:\JSONDatatest.json', 'w') as f:
     json.dump(get_list_of_dirs(path), f)
```

**Edited:**

```
import os, json, sys

def all_dirs_with_subdirs(path,subdirs):
    # make sure no relative paths are returned, can be omitted
    try:
        output_dictonary = {}

        path = os.path.abspath(path)

        list_of_dirs = []
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            if all(subdir in dirs for subdir in subdirs):
                    list_of_dirs.append(root)
        return list_of_dirs
        output_dictonary["text"] = path.decode('latin1')
        output_dictonary["type"] = "directory"

        output_dictonary["children"] = []
        for dir in list_of_dirs:
            output_dictonary["children"].append(all_dirs_with_subdirs(dir))
        return output_dictonary
    except WindowsError:
        pass

with open(r'U:\jsontesting\JSONData.json', 'w') as f:
     json.dump(all_dirs_with_subdirs("G:\TESTPATH", ('Maps', 'Temp')), f)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking you're looking for the `os.walk` command, I've implemented a function using it below. (Also made it slightly more generic)

```
import os

# path   : string to relative or absolute path to be queried
# subdirs: tuple or list containing all names of subfolders that need to be
#          present in the directory
def all_dirs_with_subdirs(path, subdirs):
    # make sure no relative paths are returned, can be omitted
    path = os.path.abspath(path)

    result = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        if all(subdir in dirs for subdir in subdirs):
                result.append(root)
    return result

def get_directory_listing(path):
    output = {}
    output["text"] = path.decode('latin1')
    output["type"] = "directory"
    output["children"] = all_dirs_with_subdirs(path, ('Maps', 'Reports'))
    return output

with open('test.json', 'w+') as f:
    listing = get_directory_listing(".")
    json.dump(listing, f)
```

**UPDATE: Also the JSON stuff**

Comment: P.S. I know I haven't mentioned the json thing, I figured encoding an array of unicode symbols in json isn't really a problem anymore since that part should work atm.

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly.  However JSON is having trouble picking up the parent/child tree of that output list.  I have tried using this to convert with json but it is just spitting out the list of folders with no child etc.  I've added it to my question.

Comment: Awesome.  Sub-sub child folders are all being grouped as one level down child folders.  For example G:\TEST\a\b\  is on the same level as G:\TEST\a\ . Is there a way to retain thier original structure?

Comment: Basically I'm using this JSON to populate a JQuery JSTree.  As it is this works great except I have a list of hundreds of folders so when a user collapses the list it fills the page.  Need to find a way to retain parent-child-child etc structure.  I'll fiddle with it and see if I can find whats going on.

Comment: Look everything can be adapted to work in any way, surely, however at some point this goes from being an answer to your question to just doing your project for you. That having been said, to do something like this, you could use a dict to see whether a parent of the directory exists already and store this somehow in a different datastructure. Best of luck

Comment: Thanks.  I will definetely look at that.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to use glob:

```
def get_list_of_dirs():

    from glob import glob
    import os.path as path

    # get the directories containing Maps
    maps = set([path.abspath(path.join(f + path.pardir)) 
              for f in glob('**/Maps/')])
    # get the directories containing Reports
    reports = set([path.abspath(path.join(f + path.pardir)) 
                      for f in glob('**/Reports/')])
    # return the common ones
    return maps.intersection(reports)
```

You can make it more generic by passing a list of glob expressions to the function and then returning the intersection of the sets or intersecting as you go.